# Can level loss be used as a retraining method?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, character-levels

If you suffer a negative level, can you select a different combination of classes when leveling up again?

For example, Bob is fighter 5 when he is attacked by a shadow dragon and loses 3 levels. When he gains another level, can he multiclass into wizard (ftr 2/wiz 1) or does he have to level up as a fighter with the exact same feats, skill points etc.?

Comment: [Awfully similar.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/105658/8610)

Comment: The question that @HeyICanChan links to is a different *question*, but the top answer to it also answers this one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Yes

The *Dungeon Master's Guide (3.5)* p.296 and *Rules Compendium*, p.49 describe the process of level loss, but say nothing about regaining levels. Hence, there are no restrictions on what new levels you can take.

According to the D&D 3.5 FAQ, regarding a character who suffers level loss after being killed and brought back with a spell like *raise dead*:

> The character is under no obligation to make the same selection(s) when he next gains a level with XP.

The only restriction is that if you use *restoration* to quickly restore levels lost to level drain, unlike gaining new levels normally by acquiring XP, that spell only restores the same class level you lost:

> A character who regains a lost level from restoration or a similar effect must regain the same class level (and other abilities) that he lost. In other words, you can't use level drain and restoration to rebuild your character.

Comment: Edited answer to make it clear that _restoration_ can only store levels lost to level drain, not to death.

Answer (score 6):

It depends. If it's strictly a "[negative level](http://dndsrd.net/abilitiesAndConditions.html#energy-drain-and-negative-levels)" then **no**, as that is a condition. However, if you fail the 24 hour saving throw after suffering a negative level, then the negative level goes away and you [lose a level](http://dndsrd.net/abilitiesAndConditions.html#level-loss) (which is very different). In that case, **yes**, with the caveat that there is a short window, one day per caster level minus one with [restoration](http://dndsrd.net/spellsPtoR.html#restoration), and one week per caster level minus one day with [greater restoration](http://dndsrd.net/spellsPtoR.html#greater-restoration), where the spell can remove energy drain that has become a lost level (not just a negative level). In that case, you must "*restore what was lost*".

Comment: I meant level loss. I will update the post.

Comment: Please give a source

Comment: Ref http://www.d20srd.org/srd/specialAbilities.htm#energyDrainAndNegativeLevels may help.

Comment: voluntarily failing a save seems to apply, however it would raise the question of whether the character would be in-character-context aware of the consequences and be willing to make such a choice.

Comment: @nijineko You mean [voluntarily forgoing the saving throw](http://dndsrd.net/magicOverview.html#voluntarily-giving-up-a-saving-throw)? That's specific to spells (and the like) and explicit edge cases like drugs. A dude can't voluntarily forgo the saving throw against, for example, a disease or level loss. (Although a dude could totally hunt down enough penalties so failure would almost be assured, he'd still succeed on a natural 20.)